# Unable to use ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, install.packages

Getting below error while trying to install and use ggplot2

```
install.packages("ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)
```

> ```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’ In addition: Warning
>   message: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.4.3
> ```

Comment: Do you get error while installing or using? You can try step-wise. First try `install.packages("ggplot2")` and check if it works.

Comment: Try install.packages("Rcpp") and if it still does not work install a c++ compiler (command g++ in Linux might be useful)

Comment: For the error, install Rcpp. For the warning, update R; the ggplot binary was built with a later version of R than you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please perform the below mentioned steps

**1)** `install.packages("Rcpp")`

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/username/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.14.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4358875 bytes (4.2 MB)
downloaded 4.2 MB

package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\username\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file173429377309\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\username\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\Rcpp’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQJ4SRf\downloaded_packages
```

**2)** Goto C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQJ4SRf\downloaded_packages

**3)** Extract Rcpp_0.12.14.zip to C:\Users\username\Documents\R\win-library\3.4

**4)** `library(ggplot2)`